# Android Recycler View inside a custom Dialog doesn't show

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-dialog

I'm creating an Android app that shows a simple skin color picker using a custom `Dialog` and a `(horizontal) Recycler View`.

But when I show the `Dialog` (by clicking an `Edit Text`), the `Dialog` appeared but the `Recycler View` didn't like this image below. The `Dialog` only showed the `Button`.

[image: screenshot]

**Did I miss something in my codes?** Maybe in the `Recycler View Adapter`.

Here are the codes:

arrays.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="skinColors">
        <item>#f26ab8</item>
        <item>#531216</item>
        <item>#ee8c5c</item>
        <item>#8b1929</item>
        <item>#f5a20f</item>
        <item>#2b6c99</item>
        <item>#73def6</item>
        <item>#f89e0a</item>
        <item>#6e938a</item>
        <item>#132855</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

item_card_view_color.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewColor">

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

dialog_color_list_picker.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewColorList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonPilih"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_card_view_color"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPilih"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/pilih"
        android:textAllCaps="false"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

SkinColorHelper.java

```java
public class SkinColorHelper {
    public static List<Integer> getSkinColorList(Context context) {
        String[] skinColorList = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.skinColors);
        List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < skinColorList.length; i++) {
            int color = Color.parseColor(skinColorList[i]);
            output.add(color);
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

SkinColorPickerAdapter.java

```java
public class SkinColorPickerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SkinColorPickerAdapter.CardViewHolder> {
    private List<Integer> skinColorList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SkinColorPickerAdapter() {
    }

    void setSkinColorList(List<Integer> skinColorList) {
        this.skinColorList = skinColorList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ItemCardViewColorBinding binding = ItemCardViewColorBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
        return new CardViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SkinColorPickerAdapter.CardViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int color = skinColorList.get(position);
        holder.bind(color);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return skinColorList.size();
    }

    public class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private ItemCardViewColorBinding binding;

        public CardViewHolder(ItemCardViewColorBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }

        void bind(int color) {
            binding.cardViewColor.setBackgroundColor(color);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_input_measurement.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.patient.inputmeasurement.InputMeasurementActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="50dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextWarnaKulitJari"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_baseline_circle_24"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="skin color picker"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSimpan"
        android:text="@string/simpan"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

InputMeasurementActivity.java

```java
public class InputMeasurementActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    // GENERAL
    ActivityInputMeasurementBinding binding;
    String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> patientList = new ArrayList<>();
    Dialog dialog;
    DialogColorListPickerBinding dialogBinding;

    // KEYS FOR PATIENT DATA
    String keyPatientId = "id";
    String keyPatientName = "name";
    String keyPatientGender = "gender";
    String keyPatientNik = "nik";
    String keyPatientBirthDate = "birthDate";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityInputMeasurementBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialogBinding = DialogColorListPickerBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

        initializeColorListPickerDialog();
        hideProgressBar();

        binding.editTextWarnaKulitJari.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // ON CLICK LISTENER
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.editTextWarnaKulitJari) {
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    private void showProgressBar() {
        binding.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void hideProgressBar() {
        binding.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    
    private void addDataToSkinColorRecylcerView() {
        List<Integer> colorList = SkinColorHelper.getSkinColorList(this);
        Log.d(TAG, "colorListSize: " + colorList.size() + " colorList: " + colorList.toString());

        SkinColorPickerAdapter adapter = new SkinColorPickerAdapter();
        adapter.setSkinColorList(colorList);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

        dialogBinding.recyclerViewColorList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        dialogBinding.recyclerViewColorList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        dialogBinding.recyclerViewColorList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void initializeColorListPickerDialog() {
        addDataToSkinColorRecylcerView();

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_color_list_picker);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    }
}
```

Comment: RecyclerView -> android:layout_width="0dp"  android:layout_height="0dp"

Comment: thanks for the comment @javdromero 
but it doesn't work.
I have a working app with code that has 0dp for width and height for the ```recycler view``` here https://github.com/jaballogian/android-jetpack-pro-submission/blob/3-add-paging-test/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_film.xml

Comment: Have you used the layout inspector to confirm that the recycler is being shown? i.e. check that the problem is the list's size vs. the list is completely missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I saw that your adapter was set up totally wrong. I think you got confused at the end of the closely same names in your app. But the good news are, that I fixed that for you. Here is your `SkinColorPickerAdapter.class`:

```
public class SkinColorPickerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SkinColorPickerAdapter.CardViewHolder> {
    private List<Integer> skinColorList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SkinColorPickerAdapter() {
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SkinColorPickerAdapter.CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_card_view_color,parent,false);
        return new SkinColorPickerAdapter.CardViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SkinColorPickerAdapter.CardViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int color = skinColorList.get(position);
        holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(color);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return skinColorList.size();
    }

    public void setSkinColorList(List<Integer> skinColorList) {
        this.skinColorList = skinColorList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private CardView cardView;

        public CardViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.cardView = view.findViewById(R.id.cardViewColor);
        }
    }
}
```

And here your InputMeasurementActivity.class:

```
public class InputMeasurementActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    // GENERAL
    ActivityInputMeasurementBinding binding;
    String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> patientList = new ArrayList<>();
    AlertDialog dialog;
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;

    // KEYS FOR PATIENT DATA
    String keyPatientId = "id";
    String keyPatientName = "name";
    String keyPatientGender = "gender";
    String keyPatientNik = "nik";
    String keyPatientBirthDate = "birthDate";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityInputMeasurementBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        hideProgressBar();
        binding.editTextWarnaKulitJari.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    // ON CLICK LISTENER
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.editTextWarnaKulitJari) {
            initializeColorListPickerDialog();
        }
    }

    private void showProgressBar() {
        binding.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void hideProgressBar() {
        binding.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }




    private void initializeColorListPickerDialog() {


        List<Integer> colorList = SkinColorHelper.getSkinColorList(this);

        SkinColorPickerAdapter adapter = new SkinColorPickerAdapter();
        adapter.setSkinColorList(colorList);
        dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_color_list_picker,null);
        view.setClipToOutline(true);
        dialogBuilder.setView(view);


        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewColorList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        SkinColorPickerAdapter skinColorPickerAdapter = new SkinColorPickerAdapter();
        skinColorPickerAdapter.setSkinColorList(colorList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(skinColorPickerAdapter);
        dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.show();

    }
}
```

And I changed the size of your `recyclerView` in your `dialog_color_list_picker.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewColorList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonPilih"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_card_view_color"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPilih"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/pilih"
        android:textAllCaps="false"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**FINAL RESULT**

[image: result]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work.
I have a working app with code that has 0dp for width and height for the ```recycler view``` here https://github.com/jaballogian/android-jetpack-pro-submission/blob/3-add-paging-test/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_film.xml

Comment: Okey. Made an edit to my answer. I try to rebuild your app. Give me some time to help you.

Comment: I tried implementing setLayout(800, 1000) for the dialog but still, the recycler view didn't show. I tried implementing both (with wrap content for the recycler view) but still the same.

Comment: I figured it out in the answer above :)